# How to force a 500 error to test error page

Tags: apache

Ive got a static client side site (html,css,js) on a LAMP server (although no mysql or php is being used), the only server side config is done by the `.htaccess` file and the setup of the server.

I want to test my error pages, is there a way to force a 500 error in a site setup as above ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh my. Usually people want to avoid them! :-)

If you're running PHP 5.6.13 you could request a script with this content: 
`<?php function f(){f();}; f();?>` which will segfault. But this is rather obscure.

Here's a fail-safe way: write a CGI script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 1
```

and call it.